# multimaster mysql replication position

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a circular muli-master mysql setup as follows

```
                 DB1 ------> DB2 ------> DB3 --
                  |                            |
                   ------------<---------------
```

I initialized a replication on the 3 DB servers on the same data and same master position index, if this position index become non-identical would that mean for a fact that the 3 databases became inconsistent later on, considering only one master is being written to at a time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary log coordinates have nothing to do with the instances having consistent data.

You could write binary logs on DB1 for weeks, then take a backup and use it to initialize DB2. Then some time later take a backup of DB2 and use it to initialize DB3. After that, all three servers would have identical data, but quite different binary log files and indexes.

You can instead use [Global Transaction IDs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids.html) (which are not binary log coordinates) to manage replication.

In any case, it's a risk that data will get out of sync no matter how you manage the replication. You could run queries that include [non-deterministic expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html). You could [turn off binary logging temporarily](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-sql-log-bin.html). Or logs could become corrupted as they are transferred to replicas.

If you want to test that the data is consistent, use [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html).